# How to find rows that fall within time range from a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-loc

I want to find all rows from my data frame that fall between 7am and 11am inclusive

Using this code I read a csv into a data frame with the relevent data

```
df = pd.read_csv(info.csv)
amount_df = pd.DataFrame(df['amount'])
datetime_df = pd.DataFrame((pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])).dt.time)
concat_df = pd.concat([datetime_df, amount_df], axis=1)
```

the data frame looks like this:

| datetime | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 00:51:00 | 15.84 |
| 00:35:00 | 11.64 |
| 00:13:00 | 10.20 |
| 00:33:00 | 8.00 |
| 00:53:00 | 22.95 |

when I run the following code it gives me the correct times but it wont include the instances when time = 11:00:00

```
mask = (df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 6) & (df['datetime'].dt.hour >= 11)
concat_df = concat_df[~mask]
```

I have tried to use .loc but it wont return any instances of 11:00:00 exactly

Comment: You question is unclear, please remove all unnecessary code and provide a [mre] (i.e. a DataFrame constructor that builds a meaningful example, with rows that are correctly and incorrectly selected). Don't forget to provide the expected output.

Comment: please provide df which we can use for testing, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW**

In the meantime I think I found a better solution

```
df.between_time('7:00', '10:45')
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range("2024-01-01 06:00", periods=3600*6+5, freq="S")
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(len(idx))], index=idx)

print(df.between_time('7:00', '11:00'))
```

returns:

```
2024-01-01 07:00:00   3600
2024-01-01 07:00:01   3601
2024-01-01 07:00:02   3602
2024-01-01 07:00:03   3603
2024-01-01 07:00:04   3604
...                    ...
2024-01-01 10:59:56  17996
2024-01-01 10:59:57  17997
2024-01-01 10:59:58  17998
2024-01-01 10:59:59  17999
2024-01-01 11:00:00  18000
```

**OLD**

You could create a mask that additionally asks for the 11:00:00 exclusively. So to find all times between 7am and 11 am you could use:

```
mask = ((df.index.hour >= 7) & (df.index.hour <= 10)) | ((df.index.hour == 11) & (df.index.minute == 0) & (df.index.second == 0))
df1 = df[mask]
```

which gives me:

```
                         time
2024-01-01 07:00:00  07:00:00
2024-01-01 07:00:01  07:00:01
2024-01-01 07:00:02  07:00:02
                         time
2024-01-01 10:59:58  10:59:58
2024-01-01 10:59:59  10:59:59
2024-01-01 11:00:00  11:00:00
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect, that would fail to select a time like `10:30`

Comment: You are right, please see for the edit for a updated (and super simplistic) solution

Answer (score 1):

Your logic and exact data are unclear.

One sure thing, you might need to double check [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Your current code:

```
mask = (df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 6) & (df['datetime'].dt.hour >= 11)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
mask = ~(df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 6) | ~(df['datetime'].dt.hour >= 11)
```

(since not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B))

Also equivalent to:

```
mask = (df['datetime'].dt.hour > 6) | (df['datetime'].dt.hour < 11)
```

Since `NOT >=` it `<` /  `NOT <=` it `>`.

Thus, if you want to include `11` in the final selection, you must **exclude** if from your original (inverted) mask:

```
mask = (df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 6) & (df['datetime'].dt.hour > 11)
concat_df = concat_df[~mask]
```

The  logic is the same if you want to include `6`

##### now back to your original issue

"*I want to find all rows from my data frame that fall between 7am and 11am inclusive*"

Then `(df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 6) & (df['datetime'].dt.hour >= 11)` wouldn't work anyway since the hour is necessarily **EITHER** <=6 or >=11 (It can't be both) and your condition would always be False (irrespective of the >/>=).

What you probably want is:

```
mask = (df['datetime'].dt.hour >= 7) & (df['datetime'].dt.hour <= 11)
concat_df = concat_df[mask]
```

Or:

```
mask = df['datetime'].dt.hour.between(7, 11, inclusive='both')
concat_df = concat_df[mask]
```